# How can i get the IDENTITY of an inserted row via stored procedure with SQL Server, PHP and sqlsrv?

Tags: php, sql-server

Info:

- PHP 7.0.0
- SQL Server 2014
- Using sqlsrv driver

The following code may not be optimal but this is the PHP:

```
$nombre = strval($info->nombre);
$idPerfil = 0;
$sqlAltaPerfil = "{CALL AltaPerfil(?,?)}";
$paramsAltaPerfil = [
    [$nombre, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING(SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR), SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(50)],
    [&$idPerfil, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_INT, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_INT]
];
$stmtAltaPerfil = sqlsrv_query($conexion, $sqlAltaPerfil, $paramsAltaPerfil);
if($stmtAltaPerfil !== false) {
    sqlsrv_next_result($stmtAltaPerfil);
    $sqlAltaPerfilXExComp = "{CALL AltaPerfilXExamenComplementario(?, ?)}";
    foreach($info->arrayIdExComp as $idExComp){
        $idExComp = intval($idExComp);
        var_dump($idExComp);
        $paramsAltaPerfilXExComp = [
            [$idPerfil, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_INT, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_INT],
            [$idExComp, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_INT, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_INT]
        ];
        $stmtAltaPerfilXExComp = sqlsrv_query($conexion, $sqlAltaPerfilXExComp, $paramsAltaPerfilXExComp);
        if($stmtAltaPerfilXExComp !== false){
            //bien
        }
        else{
            $exito = false;
            $erroresPhp .= print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AltaPerfil](
    @Descripcion varchar(50),
    @IdPerfil int OUTPUT
) AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PERFILEXAMENCOMPLEMENTARIO (Descripcion) VALUES (@Descripcion)
    SET @IdPerfil = @@IDENTITY
    RETURN
END
```

I know by the error message i display in the client side that `$idPerfil` remains equal to 0 (line 2). The fun fact is that in SSMS the SP works just fine, but when calling it from PHP the `$idPerfil` isn't modified

---

EDIT: I found that the problem is not the code, it's a trigger in the DB that
for some reason interferes with the @@IDENTITY variable in the SP.

This is the trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[NombresPerfilesUnicos] ON [dbo].[PERFILEXAMENCOMPLEMENTARIO] INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NombrePerfil varchar(50)
    SELECT @NombrePerfil = Descripcion FROM inserted

    IF EXISTS(SELECT PEC.IdPerfil FROM PERFILEXAMENCOMPLEMENTARIO PEC WHERE Descripcion = @NombrePerfil)
        PRINT 'ERROR, la descripcion ' + @NombrePerfil + ' ya esta registrada'
    else
        INSERT INTO PERFILEXAMENCOMPLEMENTARIO SELECT Descripcion FROM inserted

END
```

So my new question is: Why this is happening? What do i have to do to keep this trigger working (modify if necessary) and make everything work?

Comment: Why don't you perform this action by selecting the identity value with alias in the SP then you can just call with required parameters from PHP.

Comment: sorry to ask, but how to?

Answer (score 3):

Try using SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead of @@Identity.

Sourced from : 
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

"***SELECT @@IDENTITY***
It returns the last IDENTITY value produced on a connection, regardless of the table that produced the value, and regardless of the scope of the statement that produced the value."

"***SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()***
It returns the last IDENTITY value produced on a connection and by a statement in the same scope, regardless of the table that produced the value."

Comment: This really should be a comment instead of an answer but IIRC you have to have 25 points before you can comment. If you include an explanation of WHY you should use SCOPE_IDENTITY this would greatly improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in the following way: and you don't need second variable if you don't have any transaction with that next in the stored procedure.Using IDENT_CURRENT with table name is much better than others because it just return you identity value of mentioned table.

--Procedure Part

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AltaPerfil](
    @Descripcion VARCHAR(50)
) AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO PERFILEXAMENCOMPLEMENTARIO(Description) VALUES (@Descripcion)

    SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('PERFILEXAMENCOMPLEMENTARIO') AS rowID
END
```

--Call From PHP replace with your variable and It will return your column rowID with value:

```
EXEC AltaPerfil 'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, all i had to do was adding  `SET NOCOUNT ON` to the SP and it magically worked

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AltaPerfil](
    @Descripcion varchar(50),
    @IdPerfil int out
) AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO PERFILEXAMENCOMPLEMENTARIO (Descripcion) VALUES (@Descripcion)
    SET @IdPerfil = @@IDENTITY
END
```

Comment: You really should use SCOPE_IDENTITY instead. See the answer from Orions Descendent for more information.